# How does a wireless router limit connected devices?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I'm using a TP-Link TL-MR3420 wireless router to provide temporary internet access in a clubhouse.  I use a wireless 3G dongle to provide the actual internet access.  I accept that lots of users sharing one 3G connection will not provide sparkling performance.  Performance is not my issue - the users will be running a very low traffic application.

I find that at about 20 connected devices no more can connect.  Windows PC's see a simple "Unable to connect message."

The router has a log feature.  Even when showing all log messages the router does not log any refused connection attempts.  I am definitely not short of IP addresses.  I have configured the router to allow up to 100 IP addresses in the DHCP pool.  I have not seen it report allocating more than about 25 addresses.

I have searched through the configuration screens without finding a setting that controls the maximum wireless clients. I have tried a lot of google searches looking for such a setting, or confirmation that there is a device imposed limit or a limit that's innate to wireless.

Is the limit at about 20 devices something innate to wireless?  Is it a design limit in the device?  Are there other devices known to have higher limits.  I'd like to get north of 35 connections.

Comment: How big is your wifi clients traffic? Maybe you are reaching max bandwith... It will not give an IP to a client it can't handle because it is out of bandwith.

Comment: The traffic is low.  I cannot put a figure on it ATM, but I don't think it's hitting any bandwidth limit set in the router.

Comment: The theorical max bandwith is not a router limitation, it's a wireless one an it is different for a, b, g or n. Can you try if with a static IP, it can handle more than 20 wireless connections at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

In new firmware TL-MR3420_V2_150319.bin

(1)Maximum number of devices that can connect to wireless network changes from 14 to 32.

This is device limitation. Not sure what happen when you use OpenWRT ...

Answer (score 1):

The 802.11 protocol family has a hard limit of 2007 concurrent clients per access point. So you're not hitting that.

It's not uncommon for mobile Wi-Fi hotspots (Wi-Fi APs with 3G/4G Internet connections) to limit themselves to small numbers of clients. This is a design decision the manufacturers make, and I'm not sure why. Maybe supporting more clients than that would take too much power and make the batteries drain too fast. Or maybe the wireless carriers that buy and resell these products insist on the limit in order to limit load on their WWAN network.

Comment: It's typically because the specification (CPU & RAM) isn't up to handling so many connections. The cheaper devices typically use lower power CPUs so can't handle the same number of connections as more expensive AP

Comment: @munrobasher Having worked on teams that have designed consumer Wi-Fi APs, and I find that explanation highly suspect. Additional clients don't take a lot of additional CPU and RAM from the host SOC, unless you're doing AES-CCMP in software, which no one does. I'd be much more likely to believe that some Wi-Fi chipset vendor has a popular cheap low power Wi-Fi radio that lacks resources to handle more than a few clients, than I would be to believe the AP's SOC lacked the CPU or RAM resources to handle more clients.

Comment: All I know is that cheaper devices have limited number of connections due to some limitation. I could be CPU, it could be RAM and yes it could be some other component. The point to the original poster is that don't assume a cheaper device can handle many connections even if they are very low bandwidth. I've got a client right now in a café situation whereby the TP-Link router has a maximum limit of 32 clients after which no-one else can cannot. The flaw with this device is that it doesn't appear to free up these connections when people leave the café

Answer (score 0):

It is likely a device limitation - perhaps artificial. Have you checked the packet loss with 20 clients connected, to make sure that an extra wouldn't push it over some threshold?

North of 35 connections is possible, but it depends on the device - typically this is scaled by adding more access points instead of a "bigger device".

Also worth noting is that the connection link speed is typically limited by the weakest connection, so if you have a G device, then essentially all the connections will be limited to G speed (unless the device supports multiple, simultaneous antennae, which your particular one does not)